# Отношения Laravel без модели

Tags: laravel

Подскажите, есть таблица `operation_name` с полями `id` и `name`

Есть модель `Kassa` и таблица `kassa` c одним из полем `operation_name_id`

Могу ли я создать отношения в `Kassa` с таблицей `operation_name` ?

Если была бы модель `OperationName` то я бы просто отношения определил таким способом

```
public function operationName()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\OperationName', 'id');
    }
```

Как это сделать без модели ???

Comment: А в чем сложность создать модель?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что нет, такое невозможно. Нужна таблица в БД и модель.

Смотрим реализацию `HasRelationships::belongsTo()`:

```
/**
 * Define an inverse one-to-one or many relationship.
 *
 * @param  string  $related
 * @param  string|null  $foreignKey
 * @param  string|null  $ownerKey
 * @param  string|null  $relation
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function belongsTo($related, $foreignKey = null, $ownerKey = null, $relation = null)
{
    // If no relation name was given, we will use this debug backtrace to extract
    // the calling method's name and use that as the relationship name as most
    // of the time this will be what we desire to use for the relationships.
    if (is_null($relation)) {
        $relation = $this->guessBelongsToRelation();
    }

    $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);

    // If no foreign key was supplied, we can use a backtrace to guess the proper
    // foreign key name by using the name of the relationship function, which
    // when combined with an "_id" should conventionally match the columns.
    if (is_null($foreignKey)) {
        $foreignKey = Str::snake($relation).'_'.$instance->getKeyName();
    }

    // Once we have the foreign key names, we'll just create a new Eloquent query
    // for the related models and returns the relationship instance which will
    // actually be responsible for retrieving and hydrating every relations.
    $ownerKey = $ownerKey ?: $instance->getKeyName();

    return $this->newBelongsTo(
        $instance->newQuery(), $this, $foreignKey, $ownerKey, $relation
    );
}
```

В конце вызывается

```
return $this->newBelongsTo(
    $instance->newQuery(), $this, $foreignKey, $ownerKey, $relation
);
```

А `$instance->newQuery()` должно быть инстансом класса `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`:

```
protected function newBelongsTo(Builder $query, Model $child, $foreignKey, $ownerKey, $relation)
{
    return new BelongsTo($query, $child, $foreignKey, $ownerKey, $relation);
}
```

А метод `newQuery()` находится в классе `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, это и есть Модель. И он нужен
для построения запросов к БД.

Вывод: без модели не обойтись.

PS. Не знаю какую задачу вы хотите решить. Если из ряда "вытащить операции с названием 'оплачено'", то
можно использовать [локальные скоупы](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes).

Пример - это добавить в Модель Kassa:

```php
/**
 * @param Builder $query
 * @return Builder
 */
public function scopePaid(Builder $query): Builder
{
    return $query->where("operation_name_id", 1);
}
```

Пример использования:

```
Kassa::paid()->get();
```